# How to destroy a thread and destruct an object properly?

Tags: c++, windows

Recently I met a problem about thread and destruction.

Here's an example, I run my code on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() { num = 100; }
    ~A() {}
    int getNum() { return num; }
private:
    int num;
};
class B
{
public:
    B() { a = new A(); }
    ~B() { delete a; }
    void start()
    {
        std::thread t(std::mem_fn(&B::func), std::ref(*this));
        t.detach();
    }
    void func()
    {
        while (flag)
        {
            std::cout << a->getNum() << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        }
    }
    void stop()
    {
        flag = false;
    }
private:
    A* a;
    bool flag = true;
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    b->start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    b->stop();
    delete b;

    while (true)
    {
        // other codes
    }
}
```

Here I called `b->stop()`, the `flag` is set to false. Then I `delete B`, so the member `a` is deleted. However, because of the `std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000)` function, thread `t` is not stopped. Then it case an error.

I tried to add a flag for sleep:

```cpp
    void func()
    {
        while (flag)
        {
            std::cout << a->getNum() << std::endl;
            sleepFlag = true;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
            sleepFlag = false;
        }
    }
    void stop()
    {
        flag = false;
        while (sleepFlag)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
```

It works. `delete b` will wait for the `b->stop()` completed. So the thread will stop before `delete a`. But if I have 10 pointers of `B`, maybe I will wait for 20s! That's not what I want.
How can I stop the thread `t` and destrct the object `b` properly?

Comment: Just `join()` the thread. However, that doesn't work with one you already detached. BTW: There are probably hundreds of questions "How to stop a thread?" here, they all provide alternative approaches to these issues. Further, it's highly likely that your approach is flawed, but that's hard to tell because it's not clear what you're trying to achieve and why you think threads are a solution to it. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You have to join the thread in `~B` and `stop`. For this to work you will have to make your `t` a member and not detach it.

Comment: It's unclear what specific problem you want to solve. Though it is clear that you are wildly underestimating the complexity that multithreading introduces. `bool flag` isn't something you can access from multiple threads. You're going to have to learn about C++' memory model before you move on to multithreading.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt @zdf @IInspectalbe Thanks for your relpies. In my system, I have a map<int, shared_ptr<B>>. After `map::clear()`, all objects in map will be destructed. Then I have many other options. If I use `join()`, the main thread will wait for all threads stop and all objects destrcted. But I don't want the main thread to wait for so long if the size of map is large. I want to know if there's a solution.

Comment: In that case, the solution is relatively simple: Make sure that the thread holds a `shared_ptr<B>` of the object it's processing. Then, deleting the map won't destroy the objects and won't force you to wait for the threads to terminate first. However, if you want to discard what the threads are working on, you way still wish to tell them about it, so they can stop processing. All in all, you seem to be re-inventing a thread pool though. Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future, maybe it's a better approach to delegate the whole thread handling elsewhere.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It really works. Thanks a lot! BTW, the thread is started with member function `B::func()`, so I add a parameter like `B::start(shared_ptr<B>&)` and `B::func(shared_ptr<B>&)`. It works but is it a safe way?